# Download file with curl from a redirected URL

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I'm trying to download a pdf from a sciencedirect link, but a link which is forcing the download. Now I want to download this to my server.

i have account and also send my username to site with curl.

link:

> http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0254058417306235/pdfft?md5=5cf0c6dff9cab2d3678a53d25e0e1a66&pid=1-s2.0-S0254058417306235-main.pdf

my code:

```
$url="http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0254058417306235/pdfft?md5=5cf0c6dff9cab2d3678a53d25e0e1a66&pid=1-s2.0-S0254058417306235-main.pdf";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
file_put_contents("a.pdf", fopen($url, 'r'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.sciencedirect.com/');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true); // Videos are needed to transfered in binary
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // That's the clue! 
$redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$result = curl_exec($ch); // $result will have your video.
curl_close($ch);
```

but this code dont work!

Comment: whats the issue are you having?

Comment: i want to direct download from link with curl but my code dont work!!

Comment: Define "don't work". What happens?

Comment: Incidentally, when I go to that URL I'm offered the opportunity to purchase the PDF, not download it. Your cURL code is executing as an anonymous, not-logged-in user.

Comment: As @ceejayoz has stated, you're trying to download an article that requires people to pay for it. This isn't legal and CURL isn't going to solve this problem.

Comment: i also pass the username and there is no problem with this.
When I open the link in the browser, redirected to 
http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022407314004221/1-s2.0-S0022407314004221-main.pdf?_tid=71c74818-8e7b-11e7-9061-00000aacb361&acdnat=1504204830_6798eb6155c5b7c720b2c9fa3d056d5d
and start download
But with a curl it does not get redirects and returns to the first page.

*download link is sample, doesn't work*

Comment: @AdamA i have account and I do not want to do illegal !!

Comment: You are **not** passing the username or password in the code you've shown.

Comment: my problem is not username!
my problem is redirected link

Comment: Yes, and the link is redirected because your cURL code doesn't do anything to log into the website first. You say "i also pass the username" but we see zero evidence of that in the code you've provided, and it's absolutely going to be necessary.